# SQL Transpose Column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to create a new table from data out of an old one.  I'd like to take one column from a table, which has ~5000 values, and make each of those values a separate column in the new table.  Then I'd like to input the data from each row into the columns.  I imagine this would be done as a query in MSSMS, but I'm not sure how.

I'm not sure how to do a table in here, but basically this is what I'd like to do-

```
Table 1:
       Col1    Col2    Col3
Row1    a      hello   world
Row2    b      why     ok
Row3    c      the     banana
Row4    d      lion    roar

Table 2:
        a      b      c       d
Row1  hello   why    the     lion
Row2  world   ok     banana  roar
```

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do this? This looks like a pivot. If you really want to see the data like that do it in a query (view or stored procedure) instead of trying to maintain two copies of the same data.

Comment: You're going to have 5000 columns? Doesn't sound good...

Comment: In general, SQL Server does not support tables or views with 5,000 columns.  (You could use sparse columns, but that could also introduce issues.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pivot and union to populate the table. Something like the below should work:

**Update in order to do this for 5000 columns in a table then you could use a cursor along with dynamic sql.

The cursor is populated with all columns in your table from sys.columns. It then iterates through the dynamic sql for each column.

The dynamic sql performs the pivot and updates your new table using the current column name passed through by the cursor.

```
Declare @sql varchar(4000),
        @Column varchar(200)

Declare curColumns cursor fast_forward for 
Select name from sys.columns where object_id = OBJECT_ID('Table1')

Open curColumns
Fetch next from curColumns into @Column

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

Set @sql = 

'Insert into Table2
Select [a], [b], [c]

from
(select col1, ' + @Column + '
from Table1 ) p

Pivot
(max(col2) for col1 in (a,b,c)
) as pvt'

exec @sql

Fetch next from curColumns into @Column
end

Close curColumns

Deallocate curColumns
```

Comment: This looks great and could work, but the problem is I can't exactly go do this for all 5000+ entries.  The a, b, and c were just as an example to show what I mean.

Comment: @JonW Sorry I hadn't realized you had 5000 columns, I've updated my answer now and hopefully this will help.